# mypy пропускает несоответствие типов внутри метода

Tags: python, mypy

```
def func1(a_value: int) -> None:
    """Тест1."""
    print(a_value)


def func2():
    """Тест2."""
    value_b = func1('11')
    print(value_b + 10)


func2()
```

при проверке mypy не выдает никаких ошибок, считает, что все в порядке.
Если же после вызова `func2` добавить строчку:

```
value_b = func1('11')
```

то сразу же идут сообщения об ошибках:

```
error: "func1" does not return a value
error: Argument 1 to "func1" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
```

Почему mypy игнорирует ошибки внутри метода `func2` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**mypy** по умолчанию не проверяет код внутри функций, у которых нет аннотаций (это позволяет добавлять аннотации постепенно - см. [Summary of gradual typing](https://peps.python.org/pep-0483/#summary-of-gradual-typing) в **PEP 483**).

Выдержка из документации:

> ### [No errors reported for obviously wrong code](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#no-errors-reported-for-obviously-wrong-code)
>
> There are several common reasons why obviously wrong code is not flagged as an error.
>
> - **The function containing the error is not annotated.** Functions that do not have any annotations (neither for any argument nor for the return type) are not type-checked, and even the most blatant type errors (e.g. `2 + 'a'`) pass silently. The solution is to add annotations. Where that isn’t possible, functions without annotations can be checked using [`--check-untyped-defs`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-check-untyped-defs).

То есть, если второй функции указать возвращаемое значение `-> None` или при вызове mypy добавить флаг `--check-untyped-defs`, тогда код внутри второй функции начнет проверяться:

```
$ mypy --check-untyped-defs test.py
test.py:8: error: "func1" does not return a value
test.py:8: error: Argument 1 to "func1" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Для любителей хардкора также могу порекомендовать флаг [`--strict`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-strict), при его включении выдаст целых 4 ошибки:

```
$ mypy --strict test.py
test.py:6: error: Function is missing a return type annotation
test.py:6: note: Use "-> None" if function does not return a value
test.py:8: error: "func1" does not return a value
test.py:8: error: Argument 1 to "func1" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
test.py:12: error: Call to untyped function "func2" in typed context
Found 4 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Включение `--strict` эквивалентно включению следующих флагов (список получен с помощью запуска `mypy -h`): `--warn-unused-configs`, `--disallow-any-generics`, `--disallow-subclassing-any`, `--disallow-untyped-calls`, `--disallow-untyped-defs`, `--disallow-incomplete-defs`, `--check-untyped-defs`, `--disallow-untyped-decorators`, `--no-implicit-optional`, `--warn-redundant-casts`, `--warn-unused-ignores`, `--warn-return-any`, `--no-implicit-reexport`, `--strict-equality`.

Собственно, нужную опцию `--check-untyped-defs` изначально нашел добавлением всех этих флагов и запуском с удалением флагов по одному.